# Bootstrapping prior to running classification learner app in Matlab

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, classification

I am trying to utilize the classification learner app in Matlab for a set of data for cancerous and noncancerous cells (6 different types of cells). Would bootstrapping the data prior to feeding the data into the app lead to an overfitting of the model since some of the algorithms might already contain a bootstrapping process? Or would it be recommended in order to generate additional data points?

Comment: I would suggest bootstrapping prior to Matlab app for additional data points. It may have a bootstrap process designed already, but additional data points are my favorite.

Comment: Thanks Sam but doesn't it potentially lead to overfitting issues?

Comment: @user2867432 possibly, but I think it depends on how complex your model is.

Comment: Bootstrapping cannot generate additional data!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?